# Unknown error from python while designing trading strategies

Tags: python, trading

I am using python to design some trading strategies. My library includes Pyalgotrade and TA-lib mainly. I got an error from the code below.

```
from pyalgotrade.tools import yahoofinance
from pyalgotrade import strategy
from pyalgotrade.barfeed import yahoofeed
from pyalgotrade.technical import stoch
from pyalgotrade import dataseries
from pyalgotrade.technical import ma
from pyalgotrade import technical
from pyalgotrade.technical import highlow
from pyalgotrade import bar
from pyalgotrade.talibext import indicator
import numpy
import talib

class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
        strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)

        self.__instrument = instrument

        barDs = self.getFeed().getDataSeries("002389.SZ")
        self.__fastk, self.__fastd = indicator.STOCHF(barDs, 24, 3)
        self.__bias = self.__fastk * 25
        self.__DD = indicator.EMA(self.__bias, 4)
        self.__LL = (self.__DD - indicator.LOW(self.__DD,21))/(indicator.MAX(self.__DD,21) - indicator.LOW(self.__DD,21))


    def onBars(self, bars):

        bar = bars[self.__instrument]
        self.info("%0.2f, %0.2f" % (bar.getClose(), self.__LL[-1]))


        # Downdload then Load the yahoo feed from the CSV file
        yahoofinance.download_daily_bars('002389.SZ', 2013, '002389.csv')
        feed = yahoofeed.Feed()
        feed.addBarsFromCSV("002389.SZ", "002389.csv")

        # Evaluate the strategy with the feed's bars.
        myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, "002389.SZ")
        myStrategy.run()
```

The error is :

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>>
```

Nothing printed out.

I think the error might be caused by the variable called self._*LL. But I have no idea about how to write self.*_DD and self.__LL in the correct way. Can someone give me a help?

Comment: What was the error you got?

Comment: @khagler,hi,I updated the error in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.__position is None` doesn't create the attribute. Use `self.__position = None`. Also remember that attributes with 2 leading underscores are considered "private" (at least in CPython implementation) and to prevent undesired, eventual access are mangled internally into `_<ClassName>__<AttributeName>`.

Fix the line `run_strategy()`. The class `MyStrategy` isn't yet fully defined at this point.

Comment: Likely it's the point where you should run the debugger :) The error happends inside the `indicator.STOCHF(barDs, 24, 3)`, and probably caused by incorrect data in barDS. `NaN` == "Not a Number" and this means that either the feed is not initialized at all, or it's initialized incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you pointing out this,but I think this should not be the problem after I changed the code. I got a new error.

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge about TA-Lib is quite limited and it's not documented in the main Pyalgotrade docs. Perhaps you should create another question and ask people w/ instant experience in that field. Don't forget to tag the question properly.

Comment: :-) The last result doesn't look like an error, it's a valid answer :) But perhaps it's not what you expected to receive. I'd suggest you to walk through the tutorial step by step and especially pay attention to the [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org/) docs

Comment: yeah,but the tutorial doesn't tell me how to write custom formula.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it already. Perhaps you should ask the author or better join the [corresponding Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pyalgotrade)